# Compute $\int_{C}\textbf{B}\cdot d\textbf{r} = 0$ directly C is a circle

Tags: integration, vector-fields, line-integrals

I need to do a direct computation of

$\int_{C}\textbf{B}\cdot d\textbf{r} $

where $\textbf{B} = (\frac{\mu_{0}I}{2\pi}\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{\mu_{0}I}{2\pi}\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},0)$ and is a magnetic field created by a electric current $I$ through origin. $C$  is a circle in $xy$-plane with center at $(x_{0},y_{0}) \neq (0,0)$ and radius $a$.

I know the line $\textbf{integral is supposed to be zero}$. But i have a hard time proving it.

Ive tried to change to polar coordinates $x = x_{0} + acos(t)$ and $y = y_{0} + asin(t)$

The expression i get is $\frac{\mu_{0}I}{2\pi} \int^{2pi}_{0} \frac{(y_{0} + asin(t) + x_{0} + acos(t) + a^2)}{(x_{0} + acos(t))^2 + (y_{0} + asin(t))^2} dt$ which is kinda hard to integrate.

I got a tips that i should just use polar coordinates centered at origin and try to argue topologically that the integral is zero which i have no clue how to do.

Any tips will be useful thanks!

Comment: Why don't you prove that the vector field is conservative?

Comment: Hmm im not sure if im allowed to do that since it says direct computation, but ill ask my professor, if i can it will be easy! Thanks!